# Report Builder 3.0 Cant Connect To Report Server

Tags: sql-server, report, reportbuilder3.0

I've tried and search to find a solution, but to no avail...I just cannot get Report Builder 3.0 for SQL Server 2014 to connect to the Report Server

Server is running, SQL Server tells me URL is http://TREVSPC:80/ReportServer/. Knowing the format is _ i use http://TREVSPC/ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER  but this fails.

I've tried putting :80 in and this fails (as I expected) .. I've uninstalled and re-installed Report Builder hoping that would help..but all to no avail.

The error message given when finally RB gives up the ghost trying to connect is unable to connect, server is unavailable, check that the server is running

Any clues anyone ?

Thanks for any help given

TrevP

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the _MSSQLSERVER I think. That's the default format but if Reporting Services Configuration Manager has the Web Service URL as just http://TREVSPC/ReportServer/ then that should work fine in Report Builder.